# JFrame won't show up. Main method not working

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

This is something new that has happened to me. I'm doing a very simple calculator for my aunt and for some reason the main method won't connect with the JFrame.

Main code with errors on line 1 4 and 5 all saying class interface or enum expected.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   Interface i = new Interface();
   i.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Second code (Jframe) I have deleted the style and all that below since it was auto generated in netbeans.

```
package kalkulator;
public class Interface extends javax.swing.JFrame {
String vse; 
String procenti;
double pro = Double.parseDouble(procenti);
double cel = Double.parseDouble(vse);

public Interface() {
    this.vse= celota.getText();
    this.procenti = procent.getText();
}
String rezult = String.valueOf(cel*pro);

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
   rezultat.setText(rezult);
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField celota;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField procent;
private javax.swing.JTextField rezultat;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The second code (JFrame) shows no mistakes. Both in the same folder [Error screen](http://prntscr.com/ejgblp). I haven't coded in quite a while so this might just be a very stupid mistake.

Comment: You are executing code outside of a method. `double pro = Double.parseDouble(procenti);` and `double cel = Double.parseDouble(vse);` and `String rezult = String.valueOf(cel*pro);` are all written at the class level. Don't do that. Instead you can move all that initialization to your constructor.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are adding any components to your JFrame nor setting any actions. What do you expect a JFrame with no components to do? Also, if there are errors in your `main`, you should show the whole code so we'll know what's missing.

Comment: Stop posting screenshots of **text**. Copy & paste the text as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` method needs a class to live in.

First of all, classes should start with capital letters, and so should the `.java` filenames they're defined in. So rename `kalkulator.java` to `Kalkulator.java` and add the class definition around it:

```
package kalkulator;

class Kalkulator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    // rest of the code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer worked on the issues I had. Do you know how I could get a string from a public class to interact with the btton?
I have this
public class racunanje {
public String vse = celota.getText();
public String procenti  = procent.getText();
public double pro = Double.parseDouble(procenti);
public double cel = Double.parseDouble(vse);
public String rezult = String.valueOf(cel*(pro/100));
 }

and I want to get this working
private void jButton1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
  rezultat.setText(rezult);    
    }

Comment: In code form:
http://prntscr.com/ejil78

and this to interact:
http://prntscr.com/ejiljc